# How to tar all files.txt in directory

Tags: bash, tar

I have installed a bunch of packages through chimp from umVIRTLFS.
It creates a files.txt for each installed package in the directory /var/log/ulfs-package/package_name/ and I want to create a tarball containing the files listed in the files.txt.
So I want to run the command tar -zvcf package_name.tar.gz -T files.txt for each folder inside /var/log/ulfs-package.

Comment: Where are the ```files.txt``` files located? Are they inside of ```/var/log/ulfs-package/package_name/``` ?

Comment: Yes, they are in those folders.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all `files.txt` files are contained within a corresponding `package_name` directory:

```sh
ULFS=/var/log/ulfs-package
for package_name in ${ULFS}/*
do
    if [ -d ${ULFS}/${package_name} ] && [ -f ${ULFS}/${package_name}/files.txt ]
    then
        tar -zvcf ${package_name}.tar.gz -T ${ULFS}/${package_name}/files.txt
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I did: 
for package_name in /var/log/ulfs-packages/*; do  tar -zvcf ${package_name}.tar.gz -T $package_name/files.txt; done